# Convert a html page (div+svg elements) to a PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, canvas, jspdf

I use librairies javascript (jspdf.js and html2canvas.js) to convert my html page (elements div and svg) to a PDF. But the export doesn't include all DIV elements.

```
function svg_to_pdf(svg, callback) {
  svgAsDataUri(svg, {}, function(svg_uri) {
    var image = document.createElement('img');

    image.src = svg_uri;
    image.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var doc = new jsPDF('portrait', 'pt');
      var dataUrl;

      canvas.width = image.width;
      canvas.height = image.height;
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
      dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
      doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 600, 400);
       callback(doc);
    }
  });
}


function download_pdf(name, dataUriString) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    link.href = dataUriString;
    link.download = name;
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
}
```

Comment: Your example seems to work fine here in Firefox and Chrome, displays the loader and gets stuck on Edge, and displays "SecurityError" on IE11. Is your example link supposed to demonstrate your issue? If yes, in which context did you try it?

Comment: this example works but if I add a div elements in the page, this div elements are not exported into the pdf

Comment: can you share a link / modify your example with a div added that demonstrates the issue?